# paperclip saving null values in db in rails2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using nested fields in a form with fields_for..I need to add multiple attachments dynamically and submit the form. In the console I am getting params for attachment as

```
"reminder"=>{"message_addl_attachments_attributes"=>{"1380913359931"=>{"attachment"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131005-4343-1cxemfz-0>}}
```

Iam not sure how to handle this in controller and save the attachment. I have built the associations properly. 
In the controller I am doing like this.

```
    def create_reminder
    @reminder = Reminder.new
    @addl = @reminder.message_addl_attachments.build(params[:reminder][:message_addl_attachments])
    @addl.save
end
```

Please find the full params in console.

```
Processing ReminderPluginController#create_reminder (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-05 00:53:33) [POST]
  Parameters: {"reminder"=>{"subject"=>"nkljkl", "body"=>"<p>jkljkljkl jlkj</p>", "email"=>"", "message_addl_attachments_attributes"=>{"1380914609923"=>{"attachment"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131005-4488-1agtr7m-0>}}}, "controller"=>"reminder_plugin", "select_batch"=>{"batch"=>"2"}, "select_department"=>{"department"=>""}, "recipients"=>"20", "authenticity_token"=>"L0py7Xdsf7JSQGqn2bdoE7EXDVN9ZmNNSwl0dbHMkfM=", "action"=>"create_reminder", "commit"=>"Send"}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/reminder/create_reminder
Completed in 459ms (DB: 217) | 302 Found [http://localhost/reminder_plugin/create_reminder]
```

But it is not saving it in my rails public directory... In the db it is saving null values also.. Please help.

==============
myview.html.erb

```
<% form_for @reminder, :url => { :action => "create_reminder"
},:html=>{:multipart=>true} do |l| %>
                <div class="addl_attachments">
              <% l.fields_for :attachments do |a| %>
                  <%= render "message_addl_attachment_fields",:f=>a  %>
              <% end %>
              <div class="add_addl_attachment">
                <%= link_to_add_addl_attachment "#{image_tag
"buttons/add_2.png" } #{t('add_txt')}", l, :attachments %>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div id="submit-button">
            <%=submit_tag "#{t('send')}", :class => 'button',
:disable_with => "#{t('please_wait')}" %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

What your first have to check:

1. Is ImageMagick installed and working
2. Does your form have the attribute "multipart=>true"

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What I am not sure is that whether I am processing the params of attachments in controller correct or not.. Because in the console the params for attachment comes as _attributes additionally..

Comment: Maybe check this link http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads :)